# Spring 3.2.6 with JDK Dynamic Proxy and DWR 2.0.2 throwing exception

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-aop, dwr

I have just upgraded my web application from spring version 3.0 to spring 3.2.6.

I am using Maven, DWR 2.0.2 and Spring AOP in this web application.

All my configuration is XML based, I am not using annotations.

Here is the code:-

**Bean configuration in sample-servlet.xml file**

```
<bean id="sampleAjaxLogic" class="com.sid.web.ajax.SampleAjaxLogicImpl">

 <property name="bimSampleLogic">
     <ref bean="bimBusinessLogic"/>
 </property>

 <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
 <!--  <aop:scoped-proxy/> -->

 <dwr:remote javascript="SampleDWRCaller">
 <dwr:include method="loadSampleData"/>

</bean>
```

**Interface used:-**

```
public interface SampleAjaxLogic 
{
 public List loadSampleData(int type);
}
```

**Class that implements the above interface:-**

```
public class SampleAjaxLogicImpl implements SampleAjaxLogic {

  private SampleBusinessLogic bimSampleLogic;

public SampleBusinessLogic getBimSampleLogic() {
    return bimSampleLogic;
}

public void setBimSampleLogic(SampleBusinessLogic bimSampleLogic) {
    this.bimSampleLogic = bimSampleLogic;
}

public List loadSampleData(int type) {
   List sampleList = bimSampleLogic.loadSampleData(type);
   return sampleList;
 }
```

}

When I upgraded my configuration files to spring version 3.2.6 and tried calling the loadSampledata() method through a DWR call, I faced the following exception:-

```
2014-01-21 15:20:29,534 [TP-Processor3] WARN org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter::warn - Method execution failed:
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class**
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Nativ e Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Native MethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(De legatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFil ter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilt er(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute( DefaultRemoter.java:431)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute( DefaultRemoter.java:283)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.han dle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle( UrlProcessor.java:101)
at org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrController.handleR equestInternal(DwrController.java:234)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractContro ller.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControll erHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAda pter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet. doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet. doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
```

This exception was getting resolved when I changed AOP configuration from 
**aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"** to **aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true"**

Now as per my knowledge, it got resolved because now the application was using **CGLIB proxy** instead of **JDK Dynamic proxy**.

Now the problem is that I don't want to use CGLIB. Is there any constraint in using JDK dynamic proxy with Spring 3.2.6?? Is there any solution to this problem?

**Note - I am already using Interfaces, so that doesn't seems to be the issue here**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's see the class that's supposed to be proxied and the method that needs to be called.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis - I have added the sample code in my original post. Please have a look at it. Thanks